# My Ruby require statement is throwing errors

Tags: ruby, require

**I brain farted and didn't look in the related question section.**
**My answer has since been found.**

(Yes, I'm new to Ruby.)
This is what my console outputs:

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- Week (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from main.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

This is my `main.rb` file:

```
require 'week.rb'

class Decade
include Week

    no_of_yrs = 10

    def no_of_months
         puts Week::FIRST_DAY
         number = 10 * 12
        puts number
    end
end

d1 = Decade.new
puts Week::FIRST_DAY

Week.weeks_in_month
Week.weeks_in_year

d1.no_of_months
```

This is my week.rb:

```
module Week
    FIRST_DAY = "Sunday"

    def Week.weeks_in_month
        puts "You have four weeks in a month"
    end

    def Week.weeks_in_year
        puts "You have 52 weeks in a year"
    end
end
```

The problem could be just some stupid naming error, but I haven't found it if it is.

Comment: Dang. I didn't look in the related questions... Herpaderp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby looks for your require modules in directories found in the `$LOAD_PATH` environment variable. If it's not there, it squawks. You can do a couple of different things to fix it:

- Include the full path or relative path in your require: *e.g.*,
  `require './weeks.rb'`
- Include the path of the file in LOAD_PATH
- Move `weeks.rb` into a path that is already in LOAD_PATH

Comment: would you advice how to perform *Include the path of the file in `LOAD_PATH`* ?

Comment: @Priti you would only add to the LOAD_PATH if you wanted to setup a new path you were going to use a lot for your own ruby library for lots of ruby programs. You can set it up by putting this line in your bash profile or shell startup script: `set LOAD_PATH=$LOAD_PATH:/my/ruby/lib`.

Answer (score 1):

```
require_relative 'week.rb'
```

should also work.

Comment: Thanks Eli (+1), I forgot about the `require_relative` option :)